# Why SELECT not selecting TESTID when pass the value to another C# form into textbox field?

Tags: c#, .net

I have application C# windows forms and I passing the TESTID value from from DATAGRID view and passing it to the text box in next form , this is the code :

LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.cs :

```
public static string testid;
```

then when double click the row in DATAGRIDVIEWwill open the other form this is the code  :

```
private void dgvResult_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            initial = 1;
            orderNo = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            PatientNo = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            PatientName = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            Age = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            Gender = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            TestName = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[10].Value.ToString();
            customerNo = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
            customerName = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
            statusName = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
            deptid = Convert.ToInt32(this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[9].Value);
            testid = this.dgvResult.CurrentRow.Cells[11].Value.ToString();
     


            LAB_RESULTS_DET_INITIAL result = new LAB_RESULTS_DET_INITIAL();
            PARA_RESULT para = new PARA_RESULT();
       


            if (deptid == 6)
            {
                para.ShowDialog();
            }

      

            else if (deptid == 10)
            {
                para.ShowDialog();
            }


        }
```

In the calling form PARA_RESULT load event , I select the order details where testid = txttestid.text
, but its not selecting the order and testid data its reading the complete order details and not reading the testid written in textbox :

```
private void PARA_RESULT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {


                if (LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.initial == 1)
                {

                    txtOrder.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.orderNo;
                    txtPno.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.PatientNo;
                    txtPname.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.PatientName;
                    txtAge.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.Age;
                    txtgender.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.Gender;
                    txtcustid.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.customerNo;
                    txtTestName.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.TestName;
                    //  textCustomer.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.customerName;
                    txtDept.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.deptid.ToString();
                    txtTestId.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.testid.ToString();
                    txtsample.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.sampleID.ToString();
                    txtSampleStatus.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.statusName.ToString();
                    txtComment.Enabled = false;

                    get_para_details();
                   
               }
```

}

this is the get_para_details void its selecting the order details for all tests not for the selected testid :

```
void get_para_details()
        {
            if (txtSampleStatus.Text == "Under Processing")
            {
                string sql = @" SELECT distinct [Para_Template_Details].serial as 'No'
                                ,para_template_details.Text as 'Title'
                                ,para_template_details.Value as 'Result'
                                ,para_template_details.unit as 'Unit'
                                ,para_template_details.reference_range as 'Reference Range'
                                 FROM [dbo].[LAB_RESULTS]

                                 inner join LabTests on LAB_RESULTS.TESTID = LabTests.TestId
                                 inner join Para_Template_Details on [Para_Template_Details].TestId = LAB_RESULTS.TESTID
                                 left join lab_packages on lab_packages.testid = labtests.TestId
  
                                 where [LAB_RESULTS].SAMPLE_STATUS in (4,5)
                                 and LAB_RESULTS.deptid in (6,10)
                                 and (LAB_RESULTS.GROUPID <> 0 or LAB_RESULTS.GROUPID = 0)
                                 and (LAB_RESULTS.packageid <> 0 or LAB_RESULTS.packageid = 0)  ";

                string condition = "";
                string order_by = "order by Para_Template_Details.serial";


                if (txtOrder.Text != "")
                {
                    condition += " and lab_results.order_id ='" + txtOrder.Text + "'";
                }

                else if (txtTestId.Text != "")
                {
                    condition += " and lab_results.testid ='" + txtTestId.Text+ "'";
                }

                DataTable dt = data.fireDatatable(string.Format(sql + condition + order_by));
                dgvResult.DataSource = dt;
                dgvResult.Refresh();
            }
}
```

What I noticed when open the PARA_RESULTS window there is a delay and testid textbox not filled direct there is delay , I put another search button on the window with get_para_details void ,
when loading the window its not select by testid but when i click the search button after load all the text box value its selecting correct data ?

How to fix the issue and execute the void get_para_details in the LOAD event only after loading the testid value in textbox ?

Comment: `txtTestId.Text = LAB_RESULT_INITIAL.testid.ToString();` isn't null or empty string? You may create `TextChanged` handler on txtTestId control and insert `get_para_details()` call in it with specifying `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTestId.Text)) { get_para_details(); }`.

Comment: @Auditive I removed get_para_result from LOAD void and created handler on txttestid TextChanged but when open the window its not execute the handler after open automatically

Comment: You added check for `(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTestId.Tetxt))` ? If yes, then there is empty testid value, so `get_para_result()` doesn't fires.